# How is Partitioning done in Hazelcast

Tags: java, partitioning, in-memory-database, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast v2.5. I have a few doubts related to partitioning in a cluster.

- How are the partitions identified ?
- When a m.get request is made how does Hazelcast identify in which partition the data resides? (
  apart from the key )
- How is partitioning done when a new member joins the cluster?
- Can I get the entries in a partition if partition-ID is entered?

Answer (score 2):

Hazelcast has [a book](http://www.hazelcast.com/resources/the-book-of-hazelcast/) that covers questions like yours.
Partitions are inner technique for providing fault-tolerance. You can set partitions count (271 by default).
As a client, you can work with more user-friendly objects, like Collections\Queues..
For maps, you can control backup-count and should hazelcast read from backups.

I guess you can manage partitions using [PartitionManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hazelcast/hazelcast/2.6.5/com/hazelcast/impl/PartitionManager.java#PartitionManager)